# How to properly display all records as arrays via JSON

Tags: json, go

I have been learning golang and coding this.

The **golang** code below display two post records from database in an array via json. At the moment this is the json response am getting when I run the code and is okay for now.

```
[
{"id":"1",
"title":"Post Title 1 ",
"content":"post content 1."
},

{"id":"2",
"title":"post Title 2 ",
"content":"post content 2 "
}
]
```

At the moment, **postlikeCount** and **postunlikeCount** are not fetched in the array because they reside in another table.

If everything works fine, am supposed to get an array like this which contains everything like the sample below.

```
[
{"id":"1",
"title":"Post Title 1 ",
"content":"post content 1.",
"postlikeCount":"2",
"postunlikeCount":"1"},

{"id":"2",
"title":"post Title 2 ",
"content":"post content 2 ",
"postlikeCount":"4",
"postunlikeCount":"0"}
]
```

Now to get **postlikeCount** and **postunlikeCount**, I have implemented two sect of codings below which I passed within post `for rows.next() functions`.

```
// get postlikeCount based on userid and postid
var userid =5
var  postlikeCount int
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as postlikeCount FROM postData WHERE postid=? and userid=?", postid,userid).Scan(&postlikeCount)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Number of postlikeCount rows are %s\n",  postlikeCount)


// get postunlikeCount  based on userid and postid

var  postunlikeCount int
err1 := db.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as postunlikeCount FROM postData WHERE postid=? and userid=?", postid,userid).Scan(&postunlikeCount)
if err1 != nil {
    log.Fatal(err1)
}

fmt.Printf("Number of postunlikeCount rows are %s\n",  postunlikeCount)
```

The above two code works fine as I can Print their respective post like and unlike counts.

**Here is my issue:**

When I tried to pass and append the **postlikeCount** and **postunlikeCount** parameters so that I can print them in json as per this line of code

```
posts = append(posts, post, postlikeCount,postunlikeCount)
```

It displays error

```
cannot postlikeCount (type int) as type post in append
cannot use postunlikeCount (type int) as type post in append
```

Does this error has to do with Struct function? I need to pass **postlikeCount and postunlikeCount** as part of json as can be seen the complete array result above.

**Here is the full working code so far:**

```
package main

import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

import "net/http"
import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"
import "log"

var db *sql.DB
var err error

type Post struct {
Id  int
Title string
Content string  

}



func getRecordPage1(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    if req.Method != "POST" {
        http.ServeFile(res, req, "getjsonRecord.html")
        return
    }


var (
post  Post
posts []Post
)

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id,title,content FROM posts")
if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, "display error, unable to select records in json", 500)
            return
        }

for rows.Next() {

var postid =post.Id
var title = post.Title
var content = post.Content

fmt.Printf("%s is now %d\n", postid, title, content)


// get postlikeCount based on userid and postid
var userid =5
var  postlikeCount int
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as postlikeCount FROM postData WHERE postid=? and userid=?", postid,userid).Scan(&postlikeCount)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Number of postlikeCount rows are %s\n",  postlikeCount)


// get postunlikeCount  based on userid and postid

var  postunlikeCount int
err1 := db.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as postunlikeCount FROM postData WHERE postid=? and userid=?", postid,userid).Scan(&postunlikeCount)
if err1 != nil {
    log.Fatal(err1)
}

fmt.Printf("Number of postunlikeCount rows are %s\n",  postunlikeCount)





rows.Scan(&post.Id, &post.Title, &post.Content)
posts = append(posts, post)

//like of code comment which causes issues
//posts = append(posts, post,postlikeCount,postunlikeCount)
}
defer rows.Close()


jsonResponse, jsonError := json.Marshal(posts)
if jsonError != nil {
fmt.Println(jsonError)
}

if jsonResponse == nil {
fmt.Println(jsonError)
} else {
res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
res.Write(jsonResponse)
 fmt.Println("Json results displayed successfully")
}



}



func homePage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(res, req, "index.html")
}

func main() {
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/golang44")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/getjsonRecord", getRecordPage1)
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
        fmt.Println("Listening on 127.0.0.1:8088")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8088", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **PostLikeCount** and **PostUnlikeCount** to **Post** struct:

```
type Post struct {
    Id              int
    Title           string
    Content         string
    PostLikeCount   int
    PostUnlikeCount int
}
```

After query "SELECT COUNT(*) as postlikeCount FROM postData ...":

```
post.PostLikeCount = postlikeCount
```

After query "SELECT COUNT(*) as postunlikeCount FROM postData ...":

```
post.PostUnlikeCount = postunlikeCount
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Nicolas Barbosa

Comment: Hi Sir Nicolas. Please I have similar issue on this post. Please I need your help. Thanks.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104623/how-to-properly-display-a-json-sub-array-within-the-main-array